# load bigquery data to datalab

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I would like to use public data from bigquery on datalab, and then into a pandas dataframe. How would I go about doing that. I have tried 3 different versions:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
QUERY = (
    'SELECT pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime FROM `bigquery-public-
    data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_20*`') --also tried without the ` and wildcard
query = client.run_sync_query('%s LIMIT 100' % QUERY)
query.timeout_ms = 10000
query.run()
```

Error: BadRequest

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.io.gbq.read_gbq("""  
SELECT pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_20*
LIMIT 10
""", project_id='bigquery-public-data')
```

Error: I am asked to give access to pandas, but when I agree, I get `This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect`.

```
%%bq query
SELECT pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_20*
LIMIT 10
```

Error: Just keeps `Running`

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes above should work after some minor changes and after you granted google access to your local machine with your email using gcloud, install and initialize.

Get the project ID by typing `bq` after you initialized gcloud with `gcloud init`.

In my first code above use `client = bigquery.Client(project_id='your project id')`

Since you granted access, the second code should work as well, just update your project ID. If you dont use the `limit` function, then this may take a long time to load since pandas will transform the data to a dataframe.

And the third code will work as well.